# Edit the Java Facet setting in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, facet

Some background: I'm getting the dreaded "Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet" error in my eclipse project. I'm using Eclipse Helios on OS X Snow Leopard.

I'm having trouble editing the java facet settings for eclipse and maven.  I've searched around and everywhere says to go to Project Properties -> Project Facet and edit the version there.  However for my instance of Eclipse, these settings are not available through the UI.

How do I edit the java facet version manually?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Found it in the project under:

/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faceted-project>
  <fixed facet="wst.jsdt.web" />
  <installed facet="java" version="1.5" />
  <installed facet="jst.web" version="2.3" />
  <installed facet="wst.jsdt.web" version="1.0" />
</faceted-project>
```

For me, I had to change the java version 1.5 to 1.6 
Thought it would be useful for others since its not well documented.

Comment: for people like me this is the **full path to XML file** : `C:\path\to\project\project_name\.settings\org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml`