# Eclipse Warning: Unknown Faceted Project

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings, eclipse-juno, facet

I have a parent Maven project (using java facet version 1.7) which includes some modules. I got the following warning from Eclipse Juno SR1:

```
Implementation of project facet java could not be found.
Functionality will be limited (Unknown Faceted Project Problem)
```

How can I get rid of this error? Quick fix didn't found anything. Interestingly, I do not have Project Facet entry in the Project properties dialog.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem, and so far haven't found a solution. 
I found some advice saying that the .settings file `org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml` should be edited. This I did but to no effect.

Comment: @Tillmann, I don't remember currently how I resolved the issue, but give a try by updating Eclipse to the most recent version. If the update function doesn't work for you begin with a fresh installation on a new folder and then you can easily install the plugins you are using by choosing File -> Import -> Install -> From Existing Installation and choose the destination of your previous Eclipse installation. After it is done, you can get rid off your old installation.

Comment: Did you try the one mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802328/edit-the-java-facet-setting-in-eclipse?rq=1

Answer (score 21):

This occurs when you upgrade your IDE or open a project from older IDE into a new one.

To solve (remove the unsupported facet):

1. open your project folder;
2. goto to .settings sub-folder
3. edit the org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml file
4. remove the installed facet that refers to your error
5. if it doesn't solve immediately (if you edit the file right in Eclipse), try to close and reopen project or restart eclipse.

After all done, you may, if not done yet, mark the correct facet to your project to work.

Comment: What if it's a facet that we *do* need?  Uninstalling it wouldn't help us there.

Comment: @Zibbobz Usually "unkown faceted" just happens when you update/downgrade your environment or has uninstalled some plugin or even migrated your project from another eclipse. In summary, when something is missing in your eclipse and is required by your project. Removing it from .xml file is just to remove the error, then, to make your project run again you should install the plugin again. With compatible version that suit you.

Comment: This solution worked OK for me. Just in step 5, refresh the project and Voila.

Answer (score 6):

Just delete the file

```
org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
```

in the `.settings` folder.

It worked for me .

Comment: I had this project file with a "java" facet with value "1.7" which exactly matched my installed JDK.  Removing the file silenced that warning for me also, but I suspect it has some side effect that I have not yet discovered.

Comment: Deleting the file caused another error for me. I had to delete only the "maven" facet line in the file.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can check your project properties. and then click the Project Facets. then show the dialog box. in dialog box u can check your project is mark to java.

in dynamic app, mark the dynamic web module, java, javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. 
I found the Eclipse project was set to use JDK1.5 and I only had Java 1.6 installed. 
After changing the version to 1.6, the offending warning disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the other answers at the time of this answer, and deleting the project (not the data) and re-importing was the only way to fix the issue for me.